# How to write every other line in a text file?

Tags: python, file-io

```
inputFile = open('original_text.txt','r')
outputFile = open('half_text.txt','w')

line = inputFile.readline()
count = 0 
for line in inputFile:
    outputFile.write(line)
    count += 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        print(line)

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

It keeps skipping the 1st line. For instance, the text file right now has 10 lines. So it prints the 3rd 5th 7th and 9th. So I'm just missing the first.

Comment: What lines do you want to go into `half_text.txt` and what lines do you want printed to standard output?

Comment: Also consider `for (i, line) in enumerate(open('original_text.txt')):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This skips the first line because you read it and throw it away before the loop.  Delete line 4,

```
line = inputFile.readline()
```

Add change the count parity to odd with

```
if count % 2 == 1:
```

For a slightly better design, use a boolean that toggles:

```
count = False
for line in inputFile:
    outputFile.write(line)
    count = not count
    if count:
        print(line)

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

I tried running the program on itself:

```
inputFile = open('this_file.py', 'r')

count = False

    outputFile.write(line)

    if count:



outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgive me for my ignorance, but I am just beginning to learn about text files. So for the file to be read I don't have to put the line = inputFile.readline()? Does the for loop accomplish that? And btw deleting line = inputFile.readline() did work. I'm just trying to better understand it.

Comment: Nope.  Once you open the file, there are several ways you can access it.  readline is just one.  The two most common ways are the "with open" as Hooting showed you, and the way I did it.  Both of them show the file as a generator -- it acts as a tuple of input lines.

Answer (score 3):

use `next` to skip the next line. You may need to watch for a `StopIteration` error on the call to next(fh) if you have odd lines.

```
outputFile = open('half_text.txt','w')

with open('original_text.txt') as fh:
    for line1 in fh:
        outputFile.write(line1)
        try:
            next(fh)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

outputFile.close()
```

Comment: IMHO that's the most pythonic way of solving the task. Just a little note: you can avoid assigning `next()` result to `line2`, since it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop will go over the file line by line and when you use the `readline`, it will advance the pointer forward inside the loop. Therefore `odd` will go over odd numbered lines and `even` goes over even numbered lines.

```
with open (path, 'r') as fi:
    for odd in fi:
        even = fi.readline()
        print ('this line is odd! :' + odd)
        print ('this line is even! :' + even)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.